# Making a stateful service load balanced and redundant

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing an application which monitors a real-time stock market feed.  Users submit a query to the service.  When a stock meets the conditions of the query, the user is alerted.

I am trying to find a good way to load balance the application, and make it redundant.

Is there a standard pattern for achieving active-active load balancing and redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

sticky sessions will accomplish the load balancing, redundancy is something that'll require more detail, unless your client can submit the same request to multiple sources.